# Switch role on submit button

Tags: user-roles

I am working on a tournament website. When you register you have the role "Member" and you can create a CPT " team".

I created a "TeamAdmin" role with capabilities to `edit_published_posts`, so the TeamAdmin can change the team name, for example.

My question is how to toggle the role on the submit button, for example on the team's creation switch the role switch to "TeamAdmin"?

Answer (score 0):

The exact solution depends on how you create a team. You will have to hook into that action. Supposing that creating a team is done by creating a post of the custom type "team" you would hook into [`save_post_team`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/), leading to something like this:

```
add_action ('save_post_team', 'wpse314398_change_team_captain_role', 10, 3);
function wpse314398_change_team_captain_role ($post_id, $post, $update) {
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  $current_user->remove_role ('Member');
  $current_user->add_role ('TeamAdmin');
  }
```

You can also keep the Member role, because users may have multiple roles in WordPress. You may also want to have a reverse function if you allow users to delete their team.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, 
Finally I made this to change status on the form submit :

> wp_insert_post($team_post);
>
> ```
>     // Get the member ID
>     $user_id = get_current_user_id();
>
>     // Change his role to Team Admin
>     wp_update_user([
>         'ID' => $user_id,
>         'role' => 'TeamAdmin'
>     ]);
> ```

And my new role is like that

> 

class oArenaRole
{
    public function __construct()
    {

```
    $this->addCap();
}

public function addRole()
{
    // Create new role for Admin Team
    add_role('TeamAdmin', 'Administrateur de la team', [
        'read' => true,
        'edit_published_posts' => true,
    ]);
}

public function addCap()
{
    $role = get_role('Team Admin');

}

public function removeRole()
{
    remove_role('TeamAdmin');
}

public function activation()
{
    $this->addRole();
    $this->addCap();
}

public function deactivation()
{
    $this->removeRole();
}
```

}

Status change on submit but no possiblities for the TeamAdmin to edit his published CPT